# Why does the windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode not apply from themes.xml but does from onCreate?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My themes.xml looks like the following. I am expecting this to allow the app to render under the hole punch camera area, but instead it creates a black bar.

```
<style name="Theme.AppName" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">always</item>

</style>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Base.Theme.AppName" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->
    <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_light_primary</item> -->
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">always</item>
</style>
```

However, if I do a similar action in my onCreate() like so...

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

        val windowInsetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
        windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())

        //window.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_ALWAYS

        setContent {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                Column(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd)) {
                    // some custom buttons
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

...and the only modification I make is uncommenting that line, I get the expected behaviour even without the `android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode` parts in the XML. Why is this? Is there way to get the XML version to work? I am testing on an S24 Ultra if it matters.